# How do I access "this" in an anonymous function?

Tags: java, static, non-static

I'm having trouble accessing `this` when writing an anonymous function.

```
public class Game extends JPanel {
    public void action() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                this.repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // Paint stuff
    }
}
```

I can't declare a new instance of my class because I can't set the class to my new instance of the class without getting static/non-static errors.

Comment: `Game.this.repaint()`

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that it was called an inner class.

Comment: Technically it's an anonymous class in your case, but the same holds true for instance inner classes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
 public void action() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                this.repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Since you are in writing anonymous inner class `Runnable` , you refer to Runnable anonymous class when you write `this.repaint().`

To refer the `Game` class  repaint, the syntax is `Game.this.repaint()`